# Not being able to edit my Many-To-Many entity in AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, many-to-many, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

When creating a Many-to-Many relationship using GraphQL for the schema, I have been unable to alter the entity created. The @manyToMany annotation enables the syntax to produce a table named "OrderUsers". But the problem lies in my inability to alter the "OrderUsers" entity. After different attempts at changing the table, I have been unable to figure out how to change it. The only attributes that are taken into the "OrderUsers" table are the id from both the User as well as Order table, which also creates only two GSIs. Also, this is using the v2 docs.

```
type User @model {
  id: ID! 
  fName: String!
  lName: String!
  phoneNumber: String!
  email: String!
  DOB: String!
  orders: [Order] @manyToMany(relationName: "OrderUsers")
  ordersByDate: [Order] @hasMany(indexName: "byOrderByDate", fields: ["id"])
  ordersByStatusDate: [Order] @hasMany(indexName: "byOrderStatusByDate", fields: ["id"])
}

type Order @model {
  id: ID!
  userId: ID! @index(name: "byOrderStatusByDate", sortKeyFields: ["status", "date"]) @index(name: "byOrderByDate", sortKeyFields: ["date"])
  status: String!
  amount: Int
  date: String!
  users: [User] @manyToMany(relationName: "OrderUsers")  # Test to see if I can tinker w/ the 'OrderUsers' tbl
  productId: ID! @index(name: "byProductOrder", sortKeyFields: ["id"])
  clubId: ID! @index(name: "byClub", sortKeyFields: ["id"])
}
```

After reviewing the AWS Amplify as well as AppSync docs, attempting to add GSIs to the 'OrderUsers' table, switch the partition key used from the 'User' entity to a composite partition key for the 'OrderUsers' table, and adding other attributes to the 'OrderUsers' table, everything gets wiped as I try to push/pull it. Since the syntax isn't stored in the schema.graphql file, I have been stuck. My expectation was that it would save into the schema and update the resolvers used for the mutation(s) & queries, but that has not been the case.

Any and all help would be appreciated,

Thank you & Happy holidays